# Exclude Post Format from next_post and prev_post

Tags: navigation, post-formats

Is there a way to exclude a specific Post Format from next_post and prev_post? I want my asides to show up in the regular list of posts on the main blog page, but when a user is navigating through single post pages with next and prev links, I don't want the asides to show up.

Comment: You'll have to search the answers here for `$page/$paged` to detemine on which page you're and the `pre_get_posts` filter to see how to intercept the query and filter stuff (like post formats) out.